# What is the XAML equivalant of this html code? (nesting text elements)

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<div>
    <p>Heading 1</p>
    <div>
        <p>Heading 1.1</p>
        <div>
            <p>Heading 1.1.1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Heading 1.2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jut trying to have each block contained in within any other block to have some more margin (indentation). I am trying to show this in a FlowDocumentReader, convert it to XPS (and/or print it), but that it is just extra info and you may suggest smarter ways of achieving the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited:**

```
    <FlowDocumentReader>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph FontSize="20">Heading 1</Paragraph>
            <Section>
                <Paragraph FontSize="18">Heading 1.1</Paragraph>
                <Section>
                    <Paragraph FontSize="16">Heading 1.1.1</Paragraph>
                </Section>
            </Section>
            <Section>
                <Paragraph FontSize="20">Heading 1.2</Paragraph>
            </Section>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentReader>
```

Comment: Tried putting inside a flow document and flow document reader but got errors, is it possible that there is something more needed to have the above code within <FlowDocumentReader>
            <FlowDocument >
                Insert the document here!                
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentReader>

Comment: @Arjang my mistake.  How about something like the above?